Cannot build libgbm on i.MX6 SoloX board with meta-freescale
I want to run an app on Electron.js 11.5.0 on my UDOO Neo board (i.MX6 SoloX). I'm using Yocto Project with meta-freescale on thud branch to build my image.
Electron.js recipe complains about libgbm.so.1 not present in the image on package_qa.
I had a look on the mesa_%.bbappend file in meta-freescale and saw that gbm is removed from the PACKAGECONFIG.
PACKAGECONFIG_remove_imxgpu   = "egl gbm"

What's the problem with GBM and the i.MX 6SoloX processor?
I just want to mention that I backported imx-gpu-viv driver 6.2.4.p4.0. for my linux kernel (4.1).
